# JupyterDash - Invalid argument `options` passed into Dropdown with ID

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly-dash, dashboard

I am trying to create a dashboard to show the ethnicity makeup in different cities for multiple years. My dataframe consists of Year, Month, City and Native variables. I pasted an image on the bottom that shows my dataframe. I also tried to replicate a Dash code that I have but I received multiple errors after executing it, and it looks like most of the errors are about the City variable. Is there any guide to get my dash to work?

```
import dash
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash  # pip install dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

#df

import dash
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash  # pip install dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

#df 

app = JupyterDash()

app.layout = html.Div([
            html.H1("Native Country of Father"), 
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='cities',
                options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in list(df.City.unique()) + ['All']],
                value='All'
            ),
            dcc.RadioItems(
                    id='xaxis-type',
                    options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in ['Linear', 'Log']],
                    value='Log',
                    labelStyle={'display': 'inline-block'}
                ),    
            dcc.Graph(id='graph-with-slider'),
            dcc.Slider(
                id='year-slider',
                min=df['Year'].min(),
                max=df['Year'].max(),
                value=df['Year'].min(),
                step=None,
                marks={str(Year): str(Year) for Year in df['Year'].unique()}
            )
            
        ],
        style={'width': '48%', 'display': 'inline-block'})


@app.callback(
    Output('graph-with-slider', 'figure'),
    [Input('year-slider', 'value'),
     Input('xaxis-type','value'),
     Input('cities','value')])

def update_figure(selected_year, axis_type, City):
    if City=="All":
        filtered_df = df
    else:
        filtered_df = df[df['City']==City]
    filtered_df = filtered_df[filtered_df.Year == selected_year]
    traces = []
    for i in filtered_df.City.unique():
        df_by_City = filtered_df[filtered_df['City'] == i]
        traces.append(go.Scatter(
            y=df_by_City['Native Country of Father'],
            text=df_by_City['Native Country of Father'],
            mode='markers',
            opacity=0.7,
            marker={
                'size': 15,
                'line': {'width': 0.5, 'color': 'white'}
            },
            name=i
        ))

    return {
        'data': traces,
        'layout': go.Layout(
            xaxis={'type': 'linear' if axis_type == 'Linear' else 'log',
                   'title': 'GDP Per Capita'},
            yaxis={'title': 'Life Expectancy', 'range': [20, 90]},
            margin={'l': 40, 'b': 40, 't': 10, 'r': 10},
            legend={'x': 0, 'y': 1},
            hovermode='closest'
        )
    }


if __name__ =='__main__':
    app.run_server(mode="external")
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have the city name in the input element dropdown, the year selected in the slider, and the x-axis set in the radio button, but is it all aligned in the callback function?

Comment: Those errors should all be self-explanatory. Expand them and read the full details. I can already see, based on the first one, that your `['All']` is incorrect for the dropdown. It needs to be a dict with a label and value.

Comment: @r-beginners Yes I believe it is aligned in the callback function.

Comment: @coralvanda do I just make a dictionary of {City: a, b, c.....} ?

Answer (score -1):

To get the dropdown working properly, you'll have to fix the value passed to options. What you have is:

```py
options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in list(df.City.unique()) + ['All']]
```

If you remove `['All']` and change the `value` prop, it should work. In order to have a value that selects everything, you need something like

```py
options=[
    {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in list(df.City.unique()) 
] + [{'label': 'All', 'value': 'All'}]
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried this but it is still giving me the same result. I am still receiving this error message "Invalid argument `options` passed into Dropdown with ID "cities"."

Comment: Wondering if it's because I have too many cities in the variable? There are probably like around 50-100 cities.

Comment: No, it can handle that many. Does it show the full value provided? It's likely the very last entry that's an issue. Can you edit your question to show that?

Comment: hey I actually started another thread with a detailed information. Would you mind checking that out?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72093071/dash-unable-to-work-dropdown-and-bar-chart

Comment: I still need to see what the last part of the error related to the `options` says. Can you show that?